How do I separate these double exposed images?
This shot was taken on a Samsung My-Cam f2.8 film camera on Kodak Gold 200, but for some reason, the winding mechanism failed and the shots which were back to back got double exposed. Luckily both the photos are 90 degrees to each other, so it's quite easy if you squint to see the other image.
I need help to find software or a person who can separate these images. They are quite precious to me.


You can not. Period.

Learn to love this photo :) Print it twice. Display both side-by-side, one rotated 90 degrees from the other - maybe in a single frame with two apertures.

@Rafael Please expand that comment a bit and post that as an answer

Relevant: https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/132833/9161

Theoretically, an AI algorithm could generate two images and then computationally double-expose them, back-optimizing the two inputs such that they generate the observed digitized image. Technically there are an infinite number of pairs which would result in the same double exposure image, but most are obvious Frankenstein's. An AI trained on what normal photos look like should be able to give you what it thinks is "most likely", though. -- I'm unaware if any such algorithms have been trained. You might have better success asking at an image-manipulation venue, rather than a photography venue.

@ArnavBadhe There are online communities that accept requests to restore or color damaged photographs.  Some of them are spookily good at it.  Maybe one of them will accept your request as an unusual challenge?

Well separating two or more photos from a multi-exposure is like asking: "I have C = A + B; given C, what is A and B?" Obviously there are multiple choices for A and B. However today, AI algorithms might create one or more plausible solutions for that challenge, but there is no guarantee that any of the "solutions" is one of the real photos. -- The other thing is that once the negative id severely over-exposed, information is lost, so it cannot be recovered any more (at least not to the original quality)

Another note: Usually you'd feel or hear if the film transport mechanism is failing; if you realize, it might save your day (by fixing the problem).

@MackM could you tell a name of maybe a link to this community?

@ArnavBadhe I am only familiar with a few, I know there are many more out there.  It is also a common paid service called 'photo restoration'.  Your case is unusual, but an interesting problem to think about.  We can all 'see' the two images, but who can tease them apart!?  They are both lovely photos, good luck!  The communities I am familiar with.  (1) https://www.reddit.com/r/estoration (2) https://www.reddit.com/r/photorestore/ (3) https://www.reddit.com/r/picrequests/

@MackM it's quite weirdly funny how the camera failed on shot 11 it skipped 12 and directly exposed shot 13 so it skipped a frame but roughly around shot 24 that's when these photos were taken I assume It had some sort of mis match on the number of photos taken vs how many frames were advanced so it just ended up re exposing the same frame that's my theory

@R.M. That sounds overly complicated, couldn't you just take something like a pretrained CLIP model and modify it so instead of outputting a caption, it outsput a float between 0 and 1 for each subpixel indicating which fraction of the color value belongs to image A. And then train it by downloading (part of) Laion5B and generating the training data by overlaying random images from Laion5B with random other images.

@U.Windl That is a long studied problem, called source separation. In fact, the Wikipedia article has an image showing exactly what OP wants. Other search terms: layer separation, layer decomposition, unbending.

@user71659 The article also states "*This problem is in general highly underdetermined, but useful solutions can be derived under a surprising variety of conditions. *" - However the human vision system does that all the time: If you look inside a shop window, you see things nicely, but when you take a photo of the same scene, you mostly see reflections in the glass. Amazingly it seems the eye has more trouble to separate the things in the photo than in real life; maybe it's the difference ein focus, but I don't really know.

@user71659 Not exactly the same, because the example there has two different blendings of the two images - here we have only one. Though we do have three color channels, which might help.

It's possible to work at this slowly through an iterative process. It takes a lot of effort and will take some artistic skill to get good results.
The basic process is:

Make a copy of the layer in photo editor.
Use clone brush and smudge to remove all details that are not part of the image in this orientation. Fill in with the color you expect should be there. Don't worry too much about removing detail, because it will come back later.
Set the mode of edited layer to Subtract (note: not the same as Difference).
You should now get most of the other photo. Adjust Brightness/Contrast or Levels setting on the edited layer to get the best result you can at this point.
Copy Merged to new image, rotate by 90 degrees and work on the opposite image.
Repeat steps, always subtracting from the original and then working on the opposite image. Note that subtraction should always be between the original image and the edited image, never between two edited images.

Any detail you remove from one image will appear in the other one. You'll need to figure out somehow what detail belongs in which image.
Here is what I got with this method in 4 iterations.
I admit it is not great, but might act as a starting point for sufficiently skilled artist to improve.



That's so useful thank you so muchhhh!

You cannot because there is no information in the image which would allow to separate them.
Closest you could get to having double exposure which you could separate is having two monochromatic objects which would expose different film crystals (channels) and then you could separate the photos somehow. Nothing like that is possible in general case and definitely not in your case.

As a commenter noted, it cannot be done automatically. But an AI (or human) could theoretically deduce from the patterns what each image ought to have been, and emit what the two source images probably were.

Could it be done if I have reference images of the place and other photos of how everyone looked that day?

@ArnavBadhe that would be more like a repainting job rather than separation that can be done in editor. It's really that difficult. "Similar" photos won't do much.

It is going to be a long task, and the results will never be "good" let alone perfect.  I'm assuming a digital tool like photoshop or gimp etc.
Start by running an edge detection filter over the whole image, to draw a thin black line around every colour transition.  You're basically "drawing lines in a cartoon"   If this doesn't produce a nice outline, then you might have to do it by hand as below.
Make backup/duplicates of this layer.
Then comes the time consuming part - to carve away any edge-line that shouldn't be there for one image.   Save often.
You have an advantage in that the two images are rotated with respect to each other, so the "wrong" image will be slightly harder to perceive.
The point here is to subtly tell viewers which bits are important and which are noise from the other image.
It may help to fade out the outlines by decreasing their opacity, so they act as guides without being too obvious.
I would suggest doing both photos, and always displaying both together.  The third composite image makes it a set of three.
Also, enjoy the artistic statement of a blended family photo.

 
The smaller the image, the better the effect.   Good luck !

thank you so much i will try that

I like the way you're thinking about it. I feel like there is something clever to be done with average color values in each overlapping segment to tease them apart more fully. In your awesome GIF example, the man on the left has two other faces overlapping his.  Can infer something about each face's contribution to the exposure based on its color outside of the overlapping region, and subtract?  They'll be odd images, but more recognizable.  A color-balancing jigsaw.

You get someone to paint the two original images, there is no other way.
I think, as said in the comments, you could get a machine learning algorithm to do the painting, but I don't think there is something ready made for this and paying a painter for, I don't know, a day of work per image, is going to be a lot cheaper than paying a software engineer for a few weeks of work to work out the machine learning model and train it.
(that being said, it seems like it would be easy to generate training data for this task, so maybe I'm overestimating the amount of work needed to train a ML model)

I'm uncomfortable suggesting this, but I'm troubled that somebody will glibly say "AI can do that!". Basically, it might be possible to tell an "AI" to detangle the two images. But it would do that by finding two "good enough" photographs somewhere on the Internet or in some other accessible archive such that their sum was fairly close to the double-exposed one. So in other words, if you asked "an AI" to do it you'd almost certainly get two photos taken by other people, not a two photos extracted from your original. It might be possible to use the found images as masks to extract something fro

@MarkMorganLloyd The probability that there exist two images on the internet that will sum up to a double-exposed input that you upload is basically 0. This prevents the machine learning model (note I never used the term "AI", that's you) from just giving you images from the training data as a response. But I did say "painting" and that's what I meant, you won't get data from nothing, someone or something will make up that data based on stuff they have seen before.

I didn't say "an exact sum", and would suggest that with their current propensity for hallucinations and gross image mismatch everybody should realise that "AIs" are extremely slapdash at this sort of thing. And please note that I have carefully quoted "AI" in both my comments: it might be artificial but it is in no way intelligent in the way that an IKBS strove to be intelligent.

@MarkMorganLloyd That you keep saying "AI" instead of talking about models makes me believe you don't know what you are talking about. Requiring the two images to "sum" (sum is a simplification) exactly to the input image is the basic and most obvious requirement for such a model and it ensures that the model can't simply output images from the internet. "hallucinations" on the other hand don't apply in the technical sense, but in a general, broad sense that's exactly what you want to the model to do: to hallucinate/guess about what the two images could have been.

@MarkMorganLloyd  The term "AI" has come to be used far too restrictively recently due to CHAT GPT and friends. AI has a range of meanings and need not mean "look for matching images". If you can conceive of a list of rules that could help a human artist to perform this task then a computer system is liable to be able to be trained similarly. This need not necesarily have access to ANY other images, although models of what human anatomy looks like may well help.

@RussellMcMahon I agree. However I'd point out that my comment was primarily "I'm troubled that somebody will glibly say 'AI'...": I'm sceptical that it can be done which is something that the other commenter appears to have ignored.

@MarkMorganLloyd If you wanted to know how such a model could work you should have asked, I have some ideas in mind that are specific enough that I was tempted to try implementing them. But frankly it's not a difficult task if you think about it (and have done computer vision before). I would probably generate Training data taking images from the Laion dataset and then do something iterative along the same vein as the algorithm described in the top voted answer.
